# Matlab installation stuck on WIndows 10 Enterprise (64 bit)

Tags: java, runtime, environment

I have installed `Windows 10` Enterprise (64 bit). I have also successfully installed the `Java Runtime Environment (v9.Build.83.x64)`.

The problem is, I cannot install any version of `Matlab` on the PC. I have tried to install different versions. Each one of the installations became stuck when I clicked on setup of `Matlab`. The installation does not run `Java` programs and only its icon in the taskbar is shown, but would not run. This also causes the PC to freeze and makes me  run task manager and end task setup of `Matlab`. I did an install and uninstall `java` but that does not help either.

What could be wrong?

Comment: This is a question for MathWorks technical support, http://www.mathworks.com/support.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you right-click the Matlab installer file “setup.exe” and select "Run as administrator".  If the installer auto-launches from the dvd, cancel the installation, then from the Start menu open “Computer”, then right click on the dvd icon and select “Open in new window” or “Open with file explorer”, the right click on the file “setup.exe” and select "Run as administrator".

Second, the Java Run time Environment may not be the same as full Java.  To be sure, go to http://www.java.com/en/download/win10.jsp and download and install java.  Windows 10’s Edge does not use java and will fight you a bit on some of the java installation sites.

Third, an old version of matlab (version 7, R14) installed for me on Windows 10, but kept crashing when I started matlab, creating a long dialog with java error references.  There are two ways to fix this.

A)  As shown in the site:
http://www.vidnis.com/2013/03/how-to-use-matlab-7-in-windows-8-and.html

1)  Go to the folder \sys\java\jre\win32.  You will find a folder with a name similar to jre1.4.2 or jre1.5.0_07.

2)  Open a new window and go to the folder C:\Program Files\Java.  You will find a folder named jre1.8.0_91, or a similar version which does not match the Java version in the Matlab folder opened in step #1.

3)  Copy (not Move) the entire folder from the folder C:\Program Files\Java to the Matlab folder opened in step #1.  You can leave the old Java folder in the Matlab folder or delete it, it doesn’t matter.

4)  In the Matlab folder opened in step #1, there is also a file named jre.cfg.  Open it with the Notepad text editor, then change the old java version number (such as 1.4.2) to the new Java version (such as 1.8.0_91).  Save the jre.cfg file and quit Notepad.

5)  Now launch MATLAB, hopefully it works.

B)  I also got matlab to run by right-clicking on the matlab.exe icon (or a shortcut icon) in directory MATLAB7\bin\win32, select “Properties”, select the tab “Compatibility”, then under “Compatibility Mode” click the checkbox “Run this program in compatibility mode for” and select “Windows Vista (Service Pack 2)” or any Vista.  None of the other options of Widows compatibility worked for me.

Good luck.